# Database Value not change using google translate in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I am changing language when user click flag icon using google translate in js, Language translate working fine, But Showing database value not changed the translation language.

For example,
Fetch username in Database logged username is `Testuser` Now I choose French language means Showing username `Testuser` itself, Not change that username in specific language.

I want to Once user choose French means username too change in that French language.

My Code:

```
<li>
    <a id="fr" href="javascript:;" title="French" onclick="trans(this.id);">
        <img src="styles/home/images/language-flag-5.png" alt="French"/>French
    </a>
</li>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit(){
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>

<script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function trans(lang){
        var nLang = lang;
        var evt;
        evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");       
        evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: "en"}, "google_translate_element");
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            angular.element('.goog-te-combo').val(nLang)[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
        }, 500);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You want to change username to other language? Maybe it's not translated because there is no such word as *Testuser* in English?

Comment: Thanx for your response,Yes want to change username and email address to other language.

Comment: Just open [Google Translater](https://translate.google.com/) paste `testuser` string into it and check what it translate into french language.

Comment: @globaltest Than your translate will make no sense. Translating email will make email address misleading. Same for username.